# how to record a audio in html5 using phone gap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, audio

I have app in which i want to record the audio in native apps using objective c but i want same audio recording for my phone gap so is there any library or frame work which we can use so that we can record audio in phone gap application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With PhoneGap you can do this with HTML/JS using the PhoneGap API.
You can find the documentation for the audio functions here:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_media_media.md.html#Media

Comment: if may i test the full example code in simple html file will it work or i have to create a new phonegap project for this to test the things

Comment: @AliSajad: No it wont. You have to create a phonegap project.